# JQuery AJAX Request Redirects Before Completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two servers: Server A, and Server B.

Server A is a central server with a web service that calls some web services on Server B, does some extra work and returns back the desired results.

Server B (OpenText Content Server) has some custom javascript on it that does the following:

On load an AJAX POST is made to get a "form" to display. The form returns as HTML and is rendered onto the page when success occurs. Here is the code:

```
function load(ID)
{
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:[REMOVED],
    data:"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><LoadForm xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><ID>" + ID + "</ID></LoadForm></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>",
    contentType:"text/xml", 
    success: render });
}

function render(data, status, jqHXR)
{
    $(fc)[0].innerHTML = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("LoadFormResult")[0].textContent;
}
```

When loading the page, the request above works without issue and renders the HTML onto the page. That content includes a button which when pressed triggers another AJAX request.

I have tried multiple different ways of redirecting... location.path, location.href, location.replace, location, history.push and all experience the same behaviour.

I've also tried the redirect in success as opposed to complete, and even redirecting just to google.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:[REMOVED],
    data:"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><CreateFolder xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><parentID>" + parentID  + "</parentID><folderDisplayName>" + folderDisplay + "</folderDisplayName><ID>" + ID + "</ID><Info>" + InfoStr + "</Info><inherit>" + inherit + "</inherit><username>" + currUser + "</username></CreateFolder></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>",
    contentType:"text/xml",
    success: goToFolder,
    error: function(d,s,j) { alert("failed"); },
    complete: function(d,t) { location.replace('[REMOVED]'); }
});
```

When I monitor with fiddler, and network monitor in IE I see the following behaviour:

1. Page loads with no issue (Which calls the first AJAX request)
2. Content gets filled in and button is pressed to generate the folder.
3. an OPTIONS call occurs to the web service first, which returns a 200 status.
4. The page receives a 302 to the root of Content Server
5. a POST call occurs to the web service, which also returns a 200 (and works)
6. By now the page has already redirected back to the root of the site. success, error, complete in the AJAX request never get executed.

If I place an alert at the end of the AJAX request that is causing the issue, and wait for a moment with that alert blocking the script; I see that the success/complete calls function (Which appropriately redirects the page to the desired location)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Additional information:

When clicking the button on the page which performs the AJAX request the following shows up in Fiddler.

OPTIONS http://mywebservice/ws/service?op=myOperation HTTP/1.1
* Returns STATUS 200 OK
GET http://contentserver/otcs/cs.exe
* Returns STATS 302 Redirect (Document Moved)
POST http://mywebservice/ws/service?op=myOpertaion HTTP/1.1
* Returns STATUS 200

Since the AJAX wouldn't respond success/complete until after the POST comes back the JavaScript doesn't execute. The alert must be blocking that GET request from occurring. No idea where that GET request is coming from.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to post to a page that's returning a 302 status code.  Can you explain that?

Comment: I'm not posting to the page returning the 302; Server A is the web service returning back the content and generating the folder (and returning back an ID) the javascript takes the form and adds it to the page, and uses the ID to redirect.

Comment: Well not directly, but you are.  Stop that and you'll fix your issue.

Comment: I guess then the question is, why would the first AJAX request to the same server not also cause a 302 to come back. While I'm using a form, I'm doing so loosely. There's no actual "form submit"

Comment: Are both ajax calls hitting the same Url?

Comment: The URL that the POST is going to is a webservice. They are both going to the same URL, with different operations. e.g,http://myserver/ws/serviceA?op=myWebMethod that web service is NOT located on server B (where the javascript is going)

Comment: So one of the calls is setting the response header to a 302 status.  Can you not modify the webservice?

Comment: I have full control over the web service. Maybe I'm confused, I'm not setting any response headers in the web service. The 302 does not come from the web service (comes from a different server). e.g, the web server (http://webservice/) returns back two 200 statuses. One on OPTIONS to the WSDL, and the other on POST for the operation. Between the OPTIONS call, and the POST call a 302 status is sent from Content Server (http://contentserver/otcs/cs.exe). This is where the JavaScript is being executed from. JavaScript definitely isn't my strong suit, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I think I'm starting to pinpoint a bit more details here, updated my question with the new information. I'm assuming that my ajax requests are not performing some rogue GET to the content server, so that has to be coming from somewhere else. I wonder if the button is doing some extra behaviour I'm not aware of. Thanks Archer, I'll begin trying to find where that GET is coming from.